# Prove an Integral Function is Differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Everything is under the Lebesgue integral setting. Fix $p \in \mathbf{R}$. Define for $y \in \mathbf{R}$,
> $$
> F(y) := \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sin(xy)}{1 + x^p} \,dx.
> $$

It can be proven that $F(y)$ is well-defined and continuous for all $p > 1$. I would now like to show $F(y)$ is differentiable for all $p > 2$ but not differentiable for when $p = 2$.

**Attempt:**
Let $y_n \to y$ in $\mathbf{R}$. Fix $p > 2$. We would like to show the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{F(y_n) - F(y)}{y_n - y}|
$$
exists. Note for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$,
$$
|\frac{F(y_n) - F(y)}{y_n - y}| = |\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y_n - y} \frac{\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)}{1 + x^p} \,dx| \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|} \frac{1}{1+x^p} \,dx.
$$
We note further that the integrand
$$
\frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|} \frac{1}{1+x^p} \to |\cos(x)|\frac{1}{1+x^p}.
$$
**If we can find a dominating integrable function (but I can't seem to find one?)**, then by LDCT we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{F(y_n) - F(y)}{y_n - y}| \leq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{|\cos(x)|}{1 + x^p} \,dx \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^p} \,dx < +\infty.
$$

For when $p = 2$, consider when $y = 0$:
$$
|\frac{F(y_n) - F(y)}{y_n - y}| =|\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y_n} \frac{\sin(xy_n)}{1 + x^p} \,dx| = |\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(xy_n)}{y_n} \frac{1}{1 + x^p} \,dx|.
$$
**How do I obtain an lower bound for this?** I believe there are some properties of the quotient
$$
\frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|}
$$
that I am missing here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**After Reading the Comment and Noticing some mistakes earlier:**

Notice the LDCT argument can be completed by choosing the Dominating function to be:
$$
\frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|} \frac{1}{1+x^p} = |x\cos(x\xi_n)| \frac{1}{1+x^p} \leq \frac{x}{1 + x^p}.
$$
The function $\frac{x}{1 + x^p}$ is indeed integrable:
$$
\int{0}{\infty} \frac{x}{1 + x^p} \,dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1 + x^p} \,dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{1 + x^p} \,dx.
$$
The first integral is finite obviously, and the second integral is finite since
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{1 + x^p} \,dx \leq \int_1 ^\infty \frac{x}{x^p} \,dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{p - 1}} \,dx < +\infty.
$$
Now to see why $F$ is not differentiable when $p = 2$, consider when $y = 0$, by Fatou's Lemma:
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{F(y_n) - F(0)}{y_n} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sin(xy_n)}{y_n} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \,dx \geq \int_0 ^\infty x\cos(0) \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \,dx.
$$
Then we have
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{F(y_n) - F(0)}{y_n} \geq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \,dx \geq \int_1 ^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \,dx \geq \int_1 ^\infty \frac{1}{2x} \,dx = +\infty.
$$
Therefore, we are done.

Comment: Hint: $$\exists\xi\in(y_n,y) \text{ s.t. } \frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|} = x\cos(x\xi)$$

Comment: @Gono So instead of the LDCT, I could just bound $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(xy_n) - \sin(xy)|}{|y_n - y|} \frac{1}{1 + x^p} \,dx = \int_0^\infty x\cos(x\xi_n) \frac{1}{1 + x^p} \,dx \leq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{x}{1 + x^p} \,dx \leq \int_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{x^{p - 1}} \,dx < +\infty$ as $p > 2$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the absolute sign on the right side (what doesn't change your proof), so it should be $|x \cos(x\xi)|$

Comment: @Gono Wait ignore my previous comment. We can just use $\frac{1}{x^{p - 1}}$ as the dominating function for LDCT, right?

Comment: @Gono But what about the lower bound?

Comment: @Gono In fact there might be something more subtle here. I didn't realize, but is the integral $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{x^{p - 1}} \,dx$ finite? I agree it is finite on any interval away from 0. But integrating from 0 might be tricky?

Comment: @Gono Sorry for the repeated messages. I updated my question with an answer that I think should be good now. Could you see if this is correct?